# Add "To-Do" flag on Q&A posts, and "To-Do" list on review page

Tags: feature-request, review

Often times I find I'm browsing through questions and answers, and I find a post that could use a bit of work but I don't immediately have the time to devote to correcting it.  It's not something that really needs to be flagged for moderator attention - usually just some sort of formatting cleanup or re-phrasing that could help the post be more valuable.  It's not something I want to clutter up comment space calling out either, because I'm perfectly willing and (provided I have privileges) able to do the work myself - I just don't have the time immediately available when I spot it, or I'd rather move on to another question at that moment and work on the issue later.

I'd like a way to flag these items for me to follow up on later.  I think it would be good to have another flag that's labeled "To-Do" or "Flag for personal review" on all Q & A posts.  Then, add a "To-Do" section to the review page that lists all the items I've flagged as such.  This would be a per-user flag that does not need to be visible to anyone else - even moderators.

It would be really good if this also came with a short "notes" field so that I could leave a comment for myself to remember what it is I wanted to do.  Additionally, it would be good if the review page alerted me to "To-Do" items that have been edited since I flagged them so that I know I need to re-consider whether action is still necessary.

Comment: Why focus on a specific post though? At any time there are more than enough posts which deserve our attention. Why would you need to come back to a particular post?

Comment: Because if I don't, then it may never get any attention.  If properly used, in the long run, this should help reduce the overall number of posts that need attention.

Comment: So not necessarily content which would end up in one of the review queues then? In any case, you could already favourite the particular question as an alternative solution.

Comment: Some apparently do, but then they forget to go check their favorites.  This is probably because that's not what favorites are meant to be used for.  Otherwise, they may as well already be called "To-Do" items.